# What are Cmdlet for remove item permanently?

Tags: powershell

I already discovered that `Remove-item` is to delete files. But I am not sure that it can delete permanently.

Or is there any other Cmdlet that can delete file permanently?

Edited:
What I mean permanently is, it is not stored in recycled bin and cannot be restored using recovery tool or other ways.

Comment: Please _edit the question_ and add more details. Explain what permanent deletion means in this context. Avoiding recycle bin? Securely deleting file contents? Something else?

Comment: have you double checked that the files are actually being sent to the Recycle Bin? posts from the psv3 era indicate that it bypasses the RB.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by removing the files permanently ? does it mean not sending to recycle bin ? Remove-item should delete the files permanently it does not send to recycle bin. It is similar to hitting the shift + delete on any file.

Comment: Yeah, that is what i want to ask. Is the file that are deleted can be recovered by any means?

Comment: Not that as of i know of. There are few tools which can read the hard disk sectors and recover the files if they sectors are not zero'd out.